# Quran 13:40; What does "show them part of what we promised them before your death" mean?

Tags: quran, quran-translation

The following translation appears in [Yusuf Ali's](http://transliteration.org/quran/WebSite_CD/MixYuwsuf/Fram2E.htm) Quran translation.

013.040 Whether We shall show thee (within thy life-time) part of what we promised them or take to ourselves thy soul (before it is all accomplished),- thy duty is to make (the Message) reach them: it is our part to call them to account.   وَ‌إِ‌ن‌ْ مَا‌ نُ‍‍رِيَ‍‍نَّ‍‍كَ بَعْ‍‍‍‍ضَ ‌الَّذِي نَعِدُهُمْ ‌أَ‌وْ‌ نَتَوَفَّيَ‍‍نَّ‍‍كَ فَإِنَّ‍‍مَا‌ عَلَ‍‍يْ‍‍كَ ‌الْبَلاَغُ ‌وَعَلَيْنَا‌ ‌الْحِسَابُ

This cannot mean in-completion of the wahi (revelation), since Muhammed (pbuh) is the seal of the prophets and one of the last ayas mention that the religion has been perfected onto you and the message is complete.

If not revelation, what is this aya referring to?

Comment: Your question is unclear and should be elaborated. It is referring to punishment. I am not sure why you think that there is any relevance to completion of revelation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What we promised them" refers to punishment in the world according to all the tafasir I looked at.

A few verses before, in the same Surah, Allah promised it to them:

> For them will be punishment in the life of [this] world, and the punishment of the Hereafter is more severe. And they will not have from Allah any protector. (13:34)

Allah tells the Prophet (SAW) that whether he sees that punishment or not, it is his job to pass on the message.

Another clue is in the verse itself:

> [...] thy duty is to make (the Message) reach them: **it is our part to call them to account.** (13:40)

The word "حِسَابُ" or "account" clearly refers to punishment for them in this context.